# Something wrong with my selected list box

Tags: c#, listbox

Basically, I want to select ABDUL SIDDIQ BIN MOHD YUSSAINI (M) on the listbox then the information of the student will be display on the right.

**Correct output:**

> Name of student:  ABDUL SIDDIQ BIN MOHD YUSSAINI
>
> Gender: (M)

But when I select abdul it display this:

> Name of student:  ABDUL SIDDIQ BIN MOHD YUSSAINI (M)
>
> Gender: ABDUL SIDDIQ BIN MOHD YUSSAINI

Here's my coding:

```
private void loadToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
  fileToolStripMenuItem.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;


  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);

  string line = "";


  while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {

   string name = "";
   string gender = "";

   char[] selected = line.ToCharArray();

   for (int i = 0; i < selected.Length; i++) {
    if (selected[i] != '(') {
     name += selected[i];

    } else if (selected[i] == '(') {
     gender += selected[i + 1];
     break;
    }

   }

   Student student = new Student();

   student.setName(name);
   student.setGender(gender);

   birthdatePicker.Value = DateTime.Now;
   studentlist.addStudent(student);
   studentListBox.Items.Add(student);


  }

  private void studentListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   string name = studentListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

   Student s = studentlist.findStudent(name);

   if (s != null) {
    s.setName(studentNameTB.Text);
    s.setGender(genderTB.Text);
    s.setBirthDate(birthdatePicker.Value);
   }
   studentNameTB.Text = studentListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
   genderTB.Text = studentListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cut down a lot of code by grabbing the selected item from the list and casting it back to its object type. For example in the click event for the listbox, get the selected object and immediately cast it to the appropriate type:

```
Student selectedStudent = (Student)listBox.SelectedItem;
```

Here's a more full example for you:

```
private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //you would fill from your file... this is just an example
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

    students.Add(new Student() { FirstName = "Joe", Gender = "Male" });
    students.Add(new Student() { FirstName = "Karen", Gender = "Female" });

    listBox.DataSource = students;
    listBox.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
}

public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string DisplayString { get { return string.Format("Name of student: {0}\r\nGender: ({1})", FirstName, Gender); } }
}

private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Student selectedStudent = (Student)listBox.SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show(selectedStudent.DisplayString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in you last two lines of code:

```
studentNameTB.Text = studentListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
genderTB.Text = studentListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

They both assign the same text to the student name and the gender box.